# I want to add a CSS-class with Typoscript conditions

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

Hey guys I am working on a Typo3 project and want to change the CSS of one nav-bar element. My thoughts: add a class via a typoscript condition but I am new to it and don't know how to achive this. Here is my Code:

```
lib {
   topNavigation = HMENU
   topNavigation {
      1 = TMENU
      1 {
        wrap = <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex text-dark align-items-end pt-4">|</ul>
        NO{
          linkWrap = <li class="nav-item text-nowrap ml-2 mr-2 pt-2">|</li>
          ATagParams = class="nav-link"
        }
      }
   }
   breadcrumbTrail = HMENU
   breadcrumbTrail {
      special = rootline
      special.range = 0|-1
      1 = TMENU
      1.NO {
         stdWrap.field = nav_title // title
         ATagTitle.field = nav_title // title
         linkWrap = | |*| &nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp; |*|
      }
      1.CUR = 1
      1.CUR {
         doNotLinkIt = 1
         stdWrap.field = nav_title // title
         linkWrap = | |*| &nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;<em>|</em>|
      }
   }
   contentTest = TEXT
   contentTest.value = 1
   contentTest.if.isTrue.numRows {
      table = tt_content
      select {
         orderBy = sorting
         where = colPos = 2
      }
   }
}
```

Here you can see how the header navigation is build and I want to add an extra class to the `ATagParams = class="nav-link"` part.

I want to achive something like this:

```
ATagParams = class="nav-link"
if.field.nav_title.equals = Spenden
ATagParams = class="nav-link nav-colored"
```

If that is even possible.

Comment: `ATagParams` is mentioned only in the TopNavigation, why have you also given the other menus? / what condition do you want to evaluate? / which TYPO3 version are you using?

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ Can't tell you why. I did not not created this, I have only taken over the project. I thought about an if condition to check if the navigation tab is "Spenden" to add extra CSS-class only for the "Spenden" tab.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ Typo3 Version 10.4.1

Comment: 10.4.9 is current. you should update.

Comment: no formating available in comments, edit your question to add this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pages does not change often you can use 'optionsplit' to modify the value fix for the `n`th menu item.

Otherwise you could use `override` with the condition.
something like:

```
lib {
   topNavigation = HMENU
   topNavigation {
      1 = TMENU
      1 {
        wrap = <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex text-dark align-items-end pt-4">|</ul>
        NO{
          linkWrap = <li class="nav-item text-nowrap ml-2 mr-2 pt-2">|</li>
          ATagParams = class="nav-link"
          ATagParams.override = class="nav-link nav-colored"
          ATagParams.override.if.equals.field = uid
          ATagParams.override.if.value = 123
        }
     :
```

when 123 is the page.uid from the page 'Spenden'

alternative:

```
          ATagParams.override.if.equals.field = nav_title
          ATagParams.override.if.value = Spenden
```

but that's more sensitive against renaming and does not work with translations.

Answer (score 0):

as you're using TYPO3 v10, I'd recommend you to use the MenuProcessor instead.
It's basically HMENU, but you can do all the styling and HTML completely in your Fluid template.

See: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing.html#menuprocessor